# Can not install steroids by missing yo

Tags: steroids, yo, appgyver

I'm using Mac OS El Capitan.
After install yo successfully

```
npm install -g yo
```

Then I install steroids:

```
npm install -g steroids
```

I got error:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY yo@>=1.0.0
```

When I check yo version:

```
yo --version
1.7.0
```

And yo path:

```
which yo
/Users/myaccount/.node/bin/yo
```

How can I fix it?